# Internal energy for polytropic process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, work

How to analyse when a certain polytropic process is given such as $ PV^r= k$ ,where $k$ is constant . I particularly want for internal energy of such process ie. How to calculate its  change in internal energy ie. $dU$ .  I would be invite if anyone can extend it ex  such as to calculate $dW$ ie. work done .

Comment: What information are you given regarding the initial and final states of the system?

Comment: I have initial and final values of pressure and temperature.

Comment: If you know the initial and final values of temperature, then you know the change in internal energy.  $\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T$, where n is determined from the ideal gas law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a polytropic process, We say that Work done by the gas is $$W=\frac{\Delta (PV)}{1-r}=\frac{P_2V_2-P_1V_1}{1-r}$$

So, Following First law of thermodynamics,
$$Q=W+\Delta U$$

Had it been adiabatic process, you could ignore $Q$ and get $\Delta U=-W$

How To derive it? $PV^r=K(constant)$

$$dW=P.dV$$
$$\int dW=K\int V^{-r}.dV$$
$$W=K\big{|}\frac{V^{1-r}}{1-r}\big{|}^{V_2}_{V_1}$$
$$W=\frac{K}{1-r}.[V_2^{1-r}-V_1^{1-r}]$$

Now you can put $K=P_1V_1 =P_2V_2$ To get your answer